# Notifying caller about error from callback in node.js on error from sqlite3 call

Tags: node.js, sqlite, callback

In node.js + sqlite3:

What is a good way to notify a caller from a callback about errors and get the caller to try again ? When we get a database locked error - would like to try and run the query again.

```
TestController.prototype.addDevices = function (number_of_devices, callback_after_all_devices_have_been_added) {
    var controller = this;
    var db = controller.connectToDb();

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_devices; i++) {
        db.each("SELECT api_key as ak FROM user_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", function(err, row) {
            //sometimes we get a SQLITE: database locked error
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log("Error found");
                //i-- this will not work - but how do we do it then?
                return;
            }
            console.log("Error: " + err);
            //code to process if we get an entry from the user_table ..
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you are getting database locked errors because of the for loop.
The for loop does not wait for the db.each to complete. It just goes on to the next iteration, after calling db.each.

Comment: but I want to carry out the db.each for the specified number of devices (i.e. the counter in the for loop) - I get database locked only sometimes and only one out of 10 times (usually on the first attempt)

Comment: You can look at async.eachSeries (async module) to ensure that a db.each gets completed before moving on to the next one.

Since your question is about how to retry, you can look at node-retry module, which will allow you to retry x number of times before failing.

Comment: thanks! will look into the modules you mention - will post if I can solve the issue using those modules. Is there any generic method by which a callback can notify a caller about errors?

Comment: the convention we follow is while calling the callback method is pass two arguments.
`callback(err, result);`

In case there is no error, just pass error = null. `callback(err);`
if error exists, then just pass the error. `callback(null, result);`

Comment: So how would that work for the db.each example?

Comment: so that becomes:
`var processData = {...};
var error = {...}; // if any;

callback_after_all_devices_have_been_added(error, processData);`

Comment: in the addDevices function, in a for loop, we are passing a callback function(err, row) to db.each. So db.each is calling our callback with err set to the error "Database locked", what we want to do is execute the caller (db.each) once again, so what needs to be modified in the code pasted above?

Comment: I tried adding an exception handler but that does not work http://pastie.org/8941791

Comment: full code here - http://pastie.org/8942159#  invoked with http://pastie.org/8942213

Comment: I managed to resolve this in this manner - is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve this - added a retry counter and moved the problem code to its own function, passing in the epilogue as a callback. It works - but is this a good way?
(other than using promises or the async module?)

```
TestController.prototype.addDevices = function (number_of_devices, callback_after_all_devices_have_been_added) {
    var number_of_users = 0;
    var controller = this;
    controller.pending_db_writes_for_device = number_of_devices;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_devices; i++) {
        var api_key = controller.getRandomAPIKeyFromDB(10,function(access_key) {
            var mac_address = controller.generateRandomMAC();
            var friendly_name = Faker.random.array_element(["Washing Machine","Television","Dishwasher","Set top box"]);
            var description = Faker.Lorem.sentence(5);
            controller.registerDeviceWithAPI(mac_address, friendly_name, description, access_key, callback_after_all_devices_have_been_added);
        });
    }
}

TestController.prototype.getRandomAPIKeyFromDB = function (retry_counter, callback) {
  var controller = this;
  var db = controller.connectToDb();
  console.log("Retry counter: "+ retry_counter);
  db.each("SELECT api_key as ak FROM user_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", function(err, row) {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log("Error: " + err + "retry count: "+ retry_counter);
                console.log("Error found");
                if(retry_counter === 0) {
                    console.log("Bailing out after retry limit reached");
                    return;
                }
                controller.getRandomAPIKeyFromDB(--retry_counter,callback);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Successfully got api key: " + row.ak);
                callback(row.ak);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: your callback (callback_after_all_devices_have_been_added) will be called ten times? That might be unexpected behavior.

Comment: yes ... thanks ... I was checking the counter for this.pending_db_writes_for_device and calling the callback_after_all_devices_have_been_added in controller.registerDeviceWithAPI only if this.pending_db_writes_for_device was zero. But I am getting different unexpected behavior now. I would be extremely grateful if you could take a look at - http://pastie.org/private/ymbkozonqe0ri1k3t78fq and tell me what can be fixed. I am getting unexpected behavior: sometimes there are duplicate entries created in the auth table.Error checking sqlite3 errors is difficult, or I am doing something wrong.